# Are Mixed Animal variations kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher

Can one consume an animal that is from two different species of the same animal?
I.e. Taurus and Tauros offspring

Comment: What's a taurus and what's a tauros (evidently two variants of bull, but what exactly is the difference)?

Comment: Do they have split hooves and chew their cud?

Comment: @Harel13 Different Types of bulls

Comment: @Dude yes they do

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119451/halachic-status-of-beefalo/119453#119453

Comment: Well, I wrote that in my question to you. Do you have a link that explicitly lists them as different variants?

Comment: @Harel13 I believe Tauros is the name of the program trying to recreate the extinct aurochs. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tauros_Programme

Comment: @JoelK ah, thanks!

Comment: @joelk I was referring to a variant of cattle. Nonetheless, whether it be a Holstein and an angus, can we eat animals that are offspring of two different species of the same animal?

Comment: @MikayahYisrael I don’t understand what you mean by two species here. Biologically speaking, Angus and Holstein cattle are the same species. Merely different breeds

Comment: @joelk my terminology was incorrect,  can we eat animals that are offspring of two different breed of the same animal?